# formula.update with function containing NA as argument value does not work

Tags: r, function, na

- **EDIT**: I made a bit simpler example of the same situation:

  I'm trying to remove one term corresponding to function `fn` from the model formula.

  ```
  f<-formula(y~x+fn(z=1))
  update(f,.~.-fn(z=1)) #remove the last term
  y ~ x 

  rm(a)
  f<-formula(y~x+fn(z=a))
  update(f,.~.-fn(z=a)) #works
  y ~ x

  #even these work:
  f<-formula(y~x+fn(z=a));update(f,.~.-fn(z=a))
  f<-formula(y~x+fn(a));update(f,.~.-fn(z=a))
  f<-formula(y~x+fn(z=a));update(f,.~.-fn(a))

  f<-formula(y~x+fn(z=NA))
  update(f,.~.-fn(z=NA)) #does not work
  y ~ x + fn(z = NA)

  #Probably something to do with environments, as these do not work:
  update(formula(y~x+fn(z=a)),.~.-fn(z=a)) #works
  y ~ x
  > update(formula(y~x+fn(z)),.~.-fn(z=a)) #nope
  y ~ x + fn(z)
  > update(formula(y~x+fn(z=a)),.~.-fn(z)) #this neither
  y ~ x + fn(z = a)
  ```

  So there's something going on in `formula.update` (or `terms.formula`) which I don't understand.

---

- Old bit; more complicated example and some digging inside of `formula.update`

  I'm trying to figure out how to update `formula` object so that I can remove some special variables relating to some functions which will be used later.

  Here is a simple example:

  ```
  f<-formula(y~x+fn(z=1))
  vars<-terms(f, c("fn"))
  rmterm<-attr(vars, "variables")[[1 + attr(vars, "specials")$fn]]   
  rmterm
  fn(z = 1)
  update(f, paste(".~.-", deparse(rmterm, width.cutoff = 500L, backtick = TRUE)))
  y ~ x
  ```

  So far everything works as expected. But if I use `NA` as an argument to `fn` the term is not removed:

  ```
  f<-formula(y~x+fn(z=NA))
  vars<-terms(f, c("fn"))
  rmterm<-attr(vars, "variables")[[1 + attr(vars, "specials")$fn]]   
  rmterm
  fn(z = NA)

  update(f, paste(".~.-", deparse(rmterm, width.cutoff = 500L, backtick = TRUE)))
  y ~ x + fn(z = NA)
  ```

  I came up with one solution to avoid this, but it feels quite hacky and it's bit difficult to generalize, as there can be several functions in formula which contain one `NA` argument and some non-`NA` arguments:

  ```
  rmterm[[2]][[1]]<-1
  f[[3]][[3]][[2]]<-1
  f<-update(f,paste(".~.-",deparse(rmterm, width.cutoff = 500L, backtick = TRUE)))
  f
  y ~ x
  rmterm[[2]][[1]]<-NA #I need the NA back
  rmterm ## NA becomes NA_real, which probably doesn't matter
  fn(z = NA_real_)
  ```

  So my question is why doesn't the `update.formula` work with `NA`'s, and what would be a good way to work around this problem?

---

- **EDIT**: looking inside the `update.formula` function:

  ```
  update.formula
  function (old, new, ...) 
  {
      tmp <- .Internal(update.formula(as.formula(old), as.formula(new)))
      out <- formula(terms.formula(tmp, simplify = TRUE))
      return(out)
  }
  ```

  - Output of `.Internal`:

    ```
    f<-formula(y~x+fn(z = NA))
    vars<-terms(f, c("fn"))
    rmterm<-attr(vars, "variables")[[1 + attr(vars, "specials")$fn]]   
    old<-f
    new<-paste(". ~ .-", deparse(rmterm, width.cutoff = 500L, backtick = TRUE))
    tmp <- .Internal(update.formula(as.formula(old), as.formula(new)))

    tmp
    y ~ (x + fn(z = NA)) - fn(z = NA)
    attr(,".Environment")
    <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
    ```
  - Looks fine. Then output of `terms.formula`:

    ```
    terms.formula(tmp, simplify = TRUE)
    y ~ x + fn(z = NA)
    attr(,"variables")
    list(y, x, fn(z = NA), fn(z = NA))
    attr(,"factors")
               x fn(z = NA)
    y          0          0
    x          1          0
    fn(z = NA) 0          1
    fn(z = NA) 0          0
    attr(,"term.labels")
    [1] "x"          "fn(z = NA)"
    attr(,"order")
    [1] 1 1
    attr(,"intercept")
    [1] 1
    attr(,"response")
    [1] 1
    attr(,".Environment")
    <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
    ```
  - This is not correct. For comparison, here's the same output when using `fn(z=1)`:

    ```
    tmp
    y ~ (x + fn(z = 1)) - fn(z = 1)
    attr(,".Environment")
    <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

    terms.formula(tmp, simplify = TRUE)
    y ~ x
    attr(,"variables")
    list(y, x, fn(z = 1))
    attr(,"factors")
              x
    y         0
    x         1
    fn(z = 1) 0
    attr(,"term.labels")
    [1] "x"
    attr(,"order")
    [1] 1
    attr(,"intercept")
    [1] 1
    attr(,"response")
    [1] 1
    attr(,".Environment")
    <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
    ```

  So it seems that the problem is somewhere in the internal `terms.formula` function.

Comment: In agreement w/ your new details: I can *add* a new term "fn(z=NA)" just fine, and subsequent to that, *remove* the `x` term, but can never remove either of the `fn(z=NA)` terms.  There's some sort of pattern match failure inside `terms.formula` I guess.

Comment: Hmmm...  try `fn(z=QQ)` and it appears to fail the same way. So maybe it's not the NA but rather a character (or unassigned object) that causes the match failure.

Comment: `fn(z=QQ)` does work for me.

Comment: The issues is in `terms.formula; it has `terms <- .Internal(terms.formula(x, specials, data, keep.order, allowDotAsName)` which doesn't catch the `fn(z = NA)` (& remove it) whereas it does catch `fn(z = 1)`. That cexecutes C code, so unless you want to delve into that, I would suggest now an email to R-Devel as this may well be a bug - though I wouldn't call it that just yet, just ask for clarification if what you are doing should work. The simplest reproducible example I got to this was: `terms.formula(y ~ (x + fn(z = NA)) - fn(z = NA))` which is what the `update.formula` code produces.

Comment: @Hemmo  yep, sorry, I had a typo in my test code.  I get a successful match on "QQ" and for that matter on `z=NULL` .

Comment: This seems to work: `f<-formula(y~x+fn(z=NA_character_));
update(f,.~.-fn(z=NA_character_))`. With `NA_real` it doesn't work.

Comment: I send an email concerning this to r-devel, so hopefully I'll get an answer from there.